# Meaning of "half fine"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "You are not a servant at the hall, of course.  You are—"  He stopped, ran his eye over my dress, which, as usual, was quite simple: a black merino cloak, a black beaver bonnet; neither of them **half fine** enough for a lady's-maid. He seemed puzzled to decide what I was; I
>   helped him.
>   "I am the governess."
>   (Jane Eyre)

What's the meaning of *half fine*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Half" modifies "fine enough".  If something isn't fine enough, then it's not suitable; if something's not *half* fine enough, then it falls *well short* of being suitable.

```
Fine enough            fineness = 1.0
Half fine enough       fineness = 0.5
Not half fine enough   fineness < 0.5
```

Both the cloak and bonnet fell well short of being suitable.